# When are facts implied in questions?

Tags: meaning

I was answering a question the other day **"How do I send an e-mail from SQL?"**. I supplied an answer dealing with the techniques necessary to perform an action in SQL, assuming that the questioner already knew how to send an email from within a program, and just needed help with the SQL.

But I wondered later: is that right? Does the question imply he knows how to send an email (from inside a program), and only needs help with the SQL part? Perhaps you could help.

Edited to clarify the meaning of 'send an email'.

Comment: OT: is he *sure* he wants to send an *email* using a *database*? O_o Fine, as far as I know this might be *possible*, but I can't picture out any situation where this might make some sense.

Comment: @Lo'oris: the question is here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704882/monitoring-mysql-database-using-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, I would assume he knows what email and SQL are, but not how to send an email from SQL.

At least for MS SQL, sending an email involves non-trivial configuration, which I would guess is probably the part he was stuck on.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that if someone even knows what SQL *is*, they would know how to do a very basic thing like sending an e-mail.

Comment: @Elendil, sorry, I didn't make clear that the questioner wanted to send mail from inside a program, which isn't quite a trivial operation. I've edited my question.